# Find overlapping dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking voor a solution for the next question.

In a table i have subscriptions with a:

```
~start_date~, ~end_date~, ~paid_till_date~
```

These subscriptions also have a ~person_id~.

Im looking to build a query to find the subscriptions for persons who have paid double for the same days and i would like the double payed subscriptions in the result of the query. Can somebody Help?

For example:

```
person_id '2' has 2 subscriptions
```

Subscription:1

```
Start_date **2017-06-30**, End_date **2017-07-14**, Paid_till_date **2017-07-07**
```

Subscription:2

```
Start_date **2017-07-03**, End_date **2017-07-17**, Paid_till_date **2017-07-10**
```

These subscriptions overlap and '2' wil pay double for a few days.

So if this is the only person_id who payed double for a few days these 2 subscriptions should be the result of the query.

Comment: well i can find them by looking for more than 2 active subscriptions by date. but compare records to other records in the same table in SQL goes beyond my knowledge at the moment...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.person_id = t.person_id and
                    t2.start_date < t.end_date and
                    t2.end_date > t.start_date and
                    t2.start_date <> t.start_date and
                    t2.end_date <> t.end_date
             );
```

Note:  This does not find a perfect overlap (where start and end dates are the same).  This is because it excludes those from the comparison to avoid determining that any record overlaps with itself.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your reply.
I dont need to know the perfect overlap, just if they cross. 

Can you help me out with de t & t2? i understand it's the table but what is the difference? and the 1 in de subbquery ?

Comment: @AntonTimmerman . . . This returns all records that overlap with other records for the same person (except exact overlaps).  `t` is your table name.  `t2` is an alias.